# Uncaught Reference error: Jquery not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, uncaught-reference-error

I'm having issues with viewing products, posts & while creating new pages ..woocommerce pages etc.
The previously created pages have the theme layout..
But new pages, product pages & post pages show like this...& if I inspect I can see

> uncaught reference error:jquery not defined at ...

The layout in pages created earlier is like this:
[image]

And that is the error layout that shows when I click a product or post or create new page
[image]

Comment: Make sure to include a code snippet in order to understand whats wrong with it.

Answer (score -1):

Add jquery script to your page as following:

```
<head>
...
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Your script here -->
</head>
```

This must be placed first before your script

Comment: where should i add it? i didn't create any new file or edited anything.. everything is set deatful for the candy themee

Comment: or you can add jQuery plugin in wordpress. [this link](https://wpengine.com/resources/jquery-wordpress/) helps you